# Ionic uploading image to server via FormData

Tags: typescript, file-upload, ionic3, multipartform-data, form-data

I would like to send an image captured from the camera to the server. I am using ionic's FileTransfer plugin for this.

```
fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options)
```

Here 'targetPath' is the actual path on the device where the image is copied after getting captured from the camera.

'URL' is something like this

```
http://my-website.com?profilePicture=?&token=?
```

'options' is

```
var options = {
  fileKey: "file",
  fileName: filename,
  chunkedMode: false,
  mimeType: "multipart/form-data"
};
```

Im unable to pass the image to the server.
Please let me know what further information is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for upload an image from camera

```
upload(id: number) {
    var api = "myapi"+id;
    const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
        fileKey: 'photo',
        fileName: 'fileName',
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        chunkedMode: false,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    }
   }
```

Comment: So you just want me to add the 'httpMethod: POST' in my options map? POST is default, so adding that would not matter. Our code is exactly similar at this point, can you think of any other thing I might be missing?

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale can you please point out what I am missing here?

Comment: No. And I tried renaming fileKey with 'photo', the server is still responding with 'No image provided'

Comment: @PrashantPimpale do you think I might have done something wrong? This is the flow I have achieved, capture an image from camera, store it in a folder in internal storage, then use the ionic file transfer plugin to upload. Im giving the

Comment: Not sure need to check with your code itself because I am not familiar with ionic